# What's next step to simplify this?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

The fraction:

$$\frac{y^2-x^2}{x-y}$$

should simplify to the answer:

$$-(x+y)$$

but the best I could do was expand it to:

$$\frac{(y+x)(y-x)}{x-y}$$

What's next step?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $x \neq y$, $$\frac{(y+x)(y-x)}{x-y} = \frac{(y+x)(y-x)}{-(y-x)}$$

$$ = -(y+x)$$
$$ = -(x+y)$$

Comment: only if $x \neq y$

Comment: I.J. Kennedy: Well, the original expression wouldn't have made sense if $x=y$.